# Python xarray: grouping by multiple parameters

Tags: python, python-xarray

When using the xarray package for Python 2.7, is it possible to group over multiple parameters like you can in pandas? In essence, an operation like:

```
data.groupby(['time.year','time.month']).mean()
```

if you wanted to get mean values for each year and month of a dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, xarray does not support grouping with multiple arguments yet. This is [something we would like to support](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/324) and it would be relatively straightforward, but nobody has had the time to implement it yet (contributions would be welcome!).

Answer (score 0):

Work on that feature is still in progress, but I have found a workaround. You can create a new coord with `assign_coords` that accurately represents your grouping dimensions and use `groupby` with that coord.

For example, if you want to group by hour and minute you effectively group by the minute of day:

```py
ds = ds.assign_coords(
    {
        "year": ds["time.year"],
        "month": ds["time.month"],
        "day": ds["time.day"],
        "minute_of_day": 60 * ds["time.hour"] + ds["time.minute"],
    }
)

ds = ds.groupby("minute_of_day").mean()
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy way around is to construct a multiindex and group by that "new" coordinate:

```py
da_multiindex = da.stack(my_multiindex=['time.year','time.month'])

da_mean = da.groupby("my_multiindex").mean()

da_mean.unstack()  # go back to normal index
```

Comment: I don't think this works. I get a `conflicting dimensions for multi-index` error when I try this. I don't think it is a solution in the case where both variables share the same dimension.